# RecyclerView error: cannot find symbol variable ao Executar o Projeto Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Meu projeto ao axecutar aparece esse erro:

```
Error:(417, 63) error: cannot find symbol variable testando
```

Local do erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O gradle do app está com todos os imports para o uso do RecyclerView correto:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.t2ti.cardapiobalcao"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //v7:22.2.1
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.17'
    compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2"
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Mesmo assim continua o erro e não consigo solucionar.

Abaixo o xml da main activity

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/txt_info1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/txt_info1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_weight="0.91"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/txt_info2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/txt_info2"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:layout_weight="1.28"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="@string/bt_incluir_item"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="cadastraItem"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:elegantTextHeight="false"
        android:background="@drawable/botao_customizado"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/txt_info3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_weight="0.14"
        android:layout_height="24dp" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="348dp">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/testando" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/txt_info4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.19"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

MainActivity abaixo modifiquei o nome da variável testando por recyclerViewTest

```
package com.t2ti.cardapiobalcao;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.t2ti.cardapio.Constantes;
import com.t2ti.cardapio.RequisicaoWebService;
import com.t2ti.cardapio.helper.CardapioContract;
import com.t2ti.cardapio.helper.DatabaseOpenHelper;
import com.t2ti.cardapio.model.DataFish;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView2;
    String url = "http://media.prefeituradeimperatriz.com.br/pVCzLbf4KZ-ADFsQ9QPGLTWRw0c=/750x0/https://d2uzqu0gkpnx87.cloudfront.net/site/content/article/recicla_catatreco.jpeg";
    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private String currentUrl;
    // CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    private RecyclerView mRVFishPrice;
    private AdapterFish mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Make call to AsyncTask


        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                boolean sentToken = sharedPreferences
                        .getBoolean(Constantes.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);
                if (!sentToken) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.msg_erro_token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
        new AsyncLogin().execute();

        //imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        //loadImagefromUrl(url);



    }



    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


/*
    public void listaItens(View view) {
        int categoria;
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case (R.id.buttonEntrada): {
                categoria = Constantes.CATEGORIA_ENTRADA;
                break;
            }
            case (R.id.buttonPratoPrincipal): {
                categoria = Constantes.CATEGORIA_PRATO_PRINCIPAL;
                break;
            }
            case (R.id.buttonBebida): {
                categoria = Constantes.CATEGORIA_BEBIDA;
                break;
            }
            case (R.id.buttonSobremesa): {
                categoria = Constantes.CATEGORIA_SOBREMESA;
                break;
            }
            default: {
                categoria = Constantes.CATEGORIA_NAO_DEFINIDA;
            }
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListaItemActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("categoria", categoria);
        startActivity(intent);
    }*/

    public void cadastraItem(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CadastraItemActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
/*
    public void pedidosPendentes(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PedidoPendenteActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
*/

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_alert_atualizacao));
            builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_alert_confirma_atualizacao));
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.txt_sim, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    new AtualizaDados().execute();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.txt_nao, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class AtualizaDados extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.msg_processando));
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                RequisicaoWebService requisicaoWebService = new RequisicaoWebService();
                List<com.t2ti.cardapio.model.DetalheDenuncia> detalhes = requisicaoWebService.getItensCardapio();

                DatabaseOpenHelper databaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(MainActivity.this);
                SQLiteDatabase db = databaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                databaseOpenHelper.onUpgrade(db, 0, 0);

                for (com.t2ti.cardapio.model.DetalheDenuncia detalhe : detalhes) {
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(CardapioContract.DetalheDenuncia._ID, detalhe.getId());
                    contentValues.put(CardapioContract.DetalheDenuncia.COLUMN_NAME_TIPO_DENUNCIA, detalhe.getTipoDenuncia());
                    contentValues.put(CardapioContract.DetalheDenuncia.COLUMN_NAME_DENUNCIADO, detalhe.getDenunciado());
                    contentValues.put(CardapioContract.DetalheDenuncia.COLUMN_NAME_LOCAL_DENUNCIA, detalhe.getDescricao());
                    contentValues.put(CardapioContract.DetalheDenuncia.COLUMN_NAME_PONTO_REFERENCIA, detalhe.getpReferencia());
                    contentValues.put(CardapioContract.DetalheDenuncia.COLUMN_NAME_DESCRICAO_DENUNCIA, detalhe.getDescricao());
                    contentValues.put(CardapioContract.DetalheDenuncia.COLUMN_NAME_URL_IMAGEM, detalhe.getUrlImagem());

                    db.insert(CardapioContract.DetalheDenuncia.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
                }
                db.close();
                return true;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean b) {
            if(b) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.msg_atualizado), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.msg_erro_atualizar), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }

    private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                // Enter URL address where your json file resides
                // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
                //url = new URL("http://192.168.1.7/test/example.json");
                url = new URL("https://cardapiobalcao-91464.firebaseapp.com/jsonData/prefeitura.json");


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {

                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return (result.toString());

                } else {

                    return ("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            List<DataFish> data=new ArrayList<>();

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    DataFish fishData = new DataFish();
                    fishData.fishImage= json_data.getString("image");
                    fishData.fishName= json_data.getString("channel");
                    fishData.catName= json_data.getString("title");
                    //fishData.sizeName= json_data.getString("size_name");
                    //fishData.price= json_data.getInt("price");
                    data.add(fishData);
                }

                // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
                mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewTest);
                mAdapter = new AdapterFish(MainActivity.this, data);
                mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Você pode editar sua postagem e adicionar o xml da activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foi resolvido, o erro ocorria por existir três Activity_main.xml coisa que eu não tinha percebido, uma estava sem o RecyclerView, e outra o Visual Studio bem que podia ter informado no erro qual Activity tava o problema, demorei quase duas semanas para resolver isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]